# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'propeller' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am trying do this tutorial

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2016/04/26/the-aviator-animating-basic-3d-scene-threejs/

and I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'propeller' of undefined;

it looks something like this:

```
                 function loop(){
                     airplane.propeller.rotation.x += 0.3;
                     sea.mesh.rotation.z += .005;
                     sky.mesh.rotation.z += .01;

                     updatePlane();

                    renderer.render(scene, camera);

                    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
                   }
```

I try and modify it :

```
                   function loop(){
                      var airplane;

                      airplane.propeller.rotation.x += 0.3;
                      sea.mesh.rotation.z += .005;
                      sky.mesh.rotation.z += .01;

                      updatePlane();

                      renderer.render(scene, camera);

                      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
                     }
```

or

```
                 function loop(){
                     var airplane = new airplane();
                     airplane.propeller.rotation.x += 0.3;
                     sea.mesh.rotation.z += .005;
                     sky.mesh.rotation.z += .01;

                     updatePlane();

                     renderer.render(scene, camera); //START THE ANIMATION,

                     requestAnimationFrame(loop);
                    }
```

but it gives the same mistake;

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You have to ensure that `airplane` is declared in a scope that is visible for the `loop()` function. I'm afraid your modifications do not really make sense. The first modification just declares a variable meaning it's still `undefined` in the next line. The second one creates the airplane each animation step which is also surely not right (you want to create the airplane 3D object just once and then reuse it).

The tutorial creates the airplane like so:

```js
var airplane;

function createPlane(){ 
    airplane = new AirPlane();
    airplane.mesh.scale.set(.25,.25,.25);
    airplane.mesh.position.y = 100;
    scene.add(airplane.mesh);
}
```

Just ensure to avoid any redeclaration of `airplane`.